# Error in very simple function

Tags: r, function

I want to make a simple function that filters all of the values in an array by removing all values less than 0.95.

JUST EDITED.. Want to know answer for educational purposes

Here is what I have:

```
significance <- function(x){
i<- 1
 while(i <= 345){

   if(x[i] < 0.95){
     x <- x[-i]
     i<- i+1

   }else{
     i<- i+1

   }

 }
  return(x)
}
```

But whenever I run it, shows the following error:

> Error in if (x[i] < 0.95) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Some threads say because it has something to do with NA values but I'm sure of having none in the dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting `length(x)` and then shortening `x`, which would cause an issue.

That said, this is not a good way to write a function like this. You should use `R`'s vectorization properties to do this much faster.

```
fun <- function(x) {
  x[x >= 0.95]
}
```

Comment: Ah i see! Thanks a lot for the help.